# Invalid argument: indices[0,0] = -4 is not in [0, 40405)

Tags: keras, word-embedding, implementation

I have a model that was kinda working on some data. I've added in some tokenized word data in the dataset (somewhat truncated for brevity):

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
comment_texts = df.comment_text.values

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(comment_texts)
comment_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(comment_texts)
maxtrainlen = max_length(comment_seq)
comment_train = pad_sequences(comment_seq, maxlen=maxtrainlen, padding='post')
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

df.comment_text = comment_train

x = df.drop('label', 1) # the thing I'm training

labels = df['label'].values  # Also known as Y

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=1337)        

n_cols = x_train.shape[1]

embedding_dim = 100  # TODO: why?

model = Sequential([
            Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_shape=(n_cols,)),
            LSTM(32),
            Dense(32, activation='relu'),
            Dense(512, activation='relu'),
            Dense(12, activation='softmax'),  # for an unknown type, we don't account for that while training
        ])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      metrics=['acc'])

# convert the y_train to a one hot encoded variable
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(labels)  # fit on all the labels
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y_train)  # encode on y_train
one_hot_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

model.fit(x_train, one_hot_y, epochs=10, batch_size=16)
```

Now, I get this error:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 12, 100)           4040500   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 32)                17024     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               16896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 12)                6156      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,081,632
Trainable params: 4,081,632
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 4702 samples
Epoch 1/10
2020-03-04 22:37:59.499238: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: indices[0,0] = -4 is not in [0, 40405)
```

I think this must be coming from my comment_text column since that is the only thing I added.

Here is what comment_text looks like before I make the substitution:
[image: before]

And here is after:
[image: after]

My full code (before I made the change) is here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y8Lhxa_DROZg0at3VR98fi5WCcunUhyc#scrollTo=hpEoqR4ne9TO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be training with `comment_train`, not with `x` which is taking whatever is in the unknown `df`.

The `embedding_dim=100` is free to choose. It's like the number of units in a hidden layer. You can tune this parameter to find which is best for your model as well as you can tune the number of units in hidden layers.

---

In your case, you will need a model with two or more inputs:

- One input for the comments, passing through the embedding and processing text
- Another input for the rest of the data, passing probably through a standard netork.

At some point you will concatenate these two branches and keep on going.

This link has a good tutorial about the **functional API** models and shows a model that has two text inputs and an extra input: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: I added a few more lines in... there are a few other columns in x (12 to be exact) that I wanted to train with. All those are numerical data, and the comments was string data which gave me an error when I tried to train. At first, I dropped the comment_text column and that worked. Now I'm trying to keep the comments in after embedding them. I think I should still be using x_train after replacing the data, no?

Comment: Embedings are for the comments. A regular model is for the rest. You must study a model with more than one input and that at some point mixes the two things.

Comment: Right. I thought I did that. After I used text_to_sequences, pad_sequences, I called this `df.comment_text = comment_train` which I think is replacing the comments in my model (text) with the embedded version (numbers). I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: An embedding can **only** train with `comment_text`, nothing else. You cannot mix the rest of the data with it. The rest of the data needs to go to **another model input** (A `Sequential` model does not support multiple inputs). You need to create a functional API model with at least two inputs, one for the embeddings, another for the rest of the data.

Comment: OH, okay. I'd need two different models?

Comment: One model with two inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209085/discussion-between-jeff-and-daniel-moller).